# Spoofs MAC Address to manufacturer of user's choice, Linux or MacOS

Tags: security, bash, linux, unix, macos

I've made a BASh script for Linux/MacOS that allows you to search for a MAC manufacturer and then generates a MAC address from that company and then spoofs it to that using `macchanger`.

You can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/keeganjk/mac-camo), or the code is put below this paragraph. To run it, `chmod +x mac-camo` and `sudo ./mac-camo`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# MAC-Camo
# Disguise your MAC Address as that of any manufacturer as you want
# Made by Keegan Kuhn
# v0.1

# Defines foreground colors
black='tput setaf 0'
red='tput setaf 1'
green='tput setaf 2'
yellow='tput setaf 3'
blue='tput setaf 4'
pink='tput setaf 5'
skyBlue='tput setaf 6'
white='tput setaf 7'
grey='tput setaf 8'

# Defines background colors
bgBlack='tput setab 0'
bgRed='tput setab 1'
bgGreen='tput setab 2'
bgYellow='tput setab 3'
bgBlue='tput setab 4'
bgPink='tput setab 5'
bgSkyBlue='tput setab 6'
bgWhite='tput setab 7'
bgGrey='tput setab 8'

# Defines other special effects
cols='tput cols'
lines='tput lines'
bold='tput bold'
reverseColor='tput rev'
underlineStart='tput smul'
underlineFinish='tput rmul'
standoutStart='tput smso'
standoutFinish='tput rmso'
stopAllFX='tput sgr0'

# Defines hexadecimal colors
hexchars="0123456789ABCDEF"

function start() {

# Renders ANSI art
$stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $bold; $red; clear
sleep .2; echo "             ▉╗   ╔▉ ╔▉▉▉╗ ╔▉▉▉▉▉        ╔▉▉▉▉▉ ╔▉▉▉╗ ▉╗   ╔▉ ╔▉▉▉╗"
sleep .2; echo "             ▉▉╗ ╔▉▉ ▉   ▉ ▉             ▉      ▉   ▉ ▉▉╗ ╔▉▉ ▉   ▉"
sleep .2; echo "             ▉ ▉▉▉ ▉ ▉▉▉▉▉ ▉      $($white)☷☷☷☷☷$($red)  ▉      ▉▉▉▉▉ ▉ ▉▉▉ ▉ ▉   ▉"
sleep .2; echo "             ▉  ▉  ▉ ▉   ▉ ▉             ▉      ▉   ▉ ▉  ▉  ▉ ▉   ▉"
sleep .2; echo "             ▉  ▉  ▉ ▉   ▉ ╚▉▉▉▉▉        ╚▉▉▉▉▉ ▉   ▉ ▉  ▉  ▉ ╚▉▉▉╝"
sleep .2; echo
sleep .2; $green; echo "  Disguise your MAC Address as that of any manufacturer as you want ($($red)MAC-Camo$($green))"
sleep .2; $skyBlue; echo "                         Made by $($green)Keegan Kuhn ($($red)keeganjk$($green))"
sleep .2; $skyBlue; echo "                                 Version: $($green)1.0"
sleep .2; echo
sleep .2; $green; echo "    Please report all issues to: $($yellow)https://github.com/keeganjk/mac-camo/issues"
$stopAllFX; $bgBlack; echo

# Checks if user is root
override="1"
if [[ $(whoami) == "root" ]]; then
  sleep .2; $green; echo "                                Root successful."
elif [[ $override == "1" ]]; then
  sleep .2; $green; echo "                                Root successful."
else
  sleep .2; $white; echo "                     Sorry, this script must be run as $($bold)root"
  sleep .4; $stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $yellow; echo "                                 Try using $($bold)sudo"
  sleep .4; $red; $bold; echo "                                  [!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)EXITING!"
  $stopAllFX; exit
fi

function spoofBrowse() {

  echo
  $blue; awk -F '#' '{printf("%10d %s\n", NR, ":" $1 )}' oui.txt
  read -p "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Enter the number code for manufacturer: >>> " num
  echo "[-] Generating MAC Address"
  num=$( expr $num - 1 )
  declare -a array
  while read -r; do
    array+=( "$REPLY" )
  done < addr.txt
  end=$( for i in {1..6} ; do echo -n ${hexchars:$(( $RANDOM % 16 )):1} ; done | sed -e 's/\(..\)/:\1/g' )
  macAddress=${array[$num]}$end
  echo "[-] MAC Address generated !"

  $skyBlue; $bold; echo
  ifconfig -l
  $white
  read -p "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Select an interface: >>> " iface
  $yellow; echo "[-] $iface selected !"
  $white; echo  "[-] Disabling $iface ..."
  ifconfig $iface down
  macchanger -m $macAddress $iface
  echo "[-] MAC Address spoofed !"
  echo "[-] Enabling $iface ..."
  ifconfig $iface up
  echo "[-] $iface enabled !"
  echo "[-] Using address: $macAddress"
  exit

}

function spoofUseMAC() {

  echo
  read -p "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Enter the number code for manufacturer: >>> " num
  echo "[-] Generating MAC Address"
  num=$( expr $num - 1 )
  declare -a array
  while read -r; do
    array+=( "$REPLY" )
  done < addr.txt
  end=$( for i in {1..6} ; do echo -n ${hexchars:$(( $RANDOM % 16 )):1} ; done | sed -e 's/\(..\)/:\1/g' )
  macAddress=${array[$num]}$end
  echo "[-] MAC Address generated !"
  echo "[-] Using address: $macAddress"

  $skyBlue; $bold; echo
  ifconfig -l
  $white
  read -p "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Select an interface: >>> " iface
  $yellow; echo "[-] $iface selected !"
  $white; echo  "[-] Disabling $iface ..."
  ifconfig $iface down
  macchanger -m $macAddress $iface
  echo "[-] MAC Address spoofed !"
  echo "[-] Enabling $iface ..."
  ifconfig $iface up
  exit

}

function spoofSearchAgainOrNot() {

  $bold; $white; echo
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Please select an option from the list below:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Search again"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Use one of these"
  read -p ">>> " searchAgainOrNot
  if [[ "$searchAgainOrNot" == "0" ]]; then
    spoofSearch
  elif [[ "$searchAgainOrNot" == "1" ]]; then
    spoofUseMAC
  else
    spoofSearchAgainOrNot
  fi

}

# Spoof, search option selected
function spoofSearch() {

  $bold; echo
  read -p "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Search for a manufacturer: >>> " search
  $blue; awk -F '#' '{printf("%10d %s\n", NR, ":" $1 )}' oui.txt | grep -i --colour="always" $search

  spoofSearchAgainOrNot

}

# Spoof
function spoof() {

  echo; $white
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Please select an option from the list below:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Search for a manufacturer"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Browse for a manufacturer through $($bold)long $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)list"
  read -p ">>> " searchOrBrowse
  if [[ $searchOrBrowse == "0" ]]; then
    spoofSearch
  elif [[ $searchOrBrowse == "1" ]]; then
    spoofBrowse
  else
    spoof
  fi

}

# Install complete
function installComplete() {

  $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[-] Install complete !"
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Restart or exit?"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Restart"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Exit"
  read -p ">>> " restartOrExit
  if [[ "$restartOrExit" == "0" ]]; then
    start
  elif [[ "$restartOrExit" == "1" ]]; then
    $yellow; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $yellow)EXITING !"
    $stopAllFX; exit
  else
    installComplete
  fi

}

# Install cancelled
function installCancelled() {

  echo; $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)INSTALL CANCELLED !"
  $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Restart or exit?"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Restart"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Exit"
  read -p ">>> " restartOrExit
  if [[ "$restartOrExit" == "0" ]]; then
    start
  elif [[ "$restartOrExit" == "1" ]]; then
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)ABORT !"
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)EXITING !"
    $stopAllFX; exit
  else
    installCancelled
  fi

}

# Linux install, Pt. 3
function linuxInstallPt3() {

  $white; $bold; echo

  echo "[-] Installing macchanger ..."
  if [[ "$pacman" == "pacman" ]]; then
    $pacman -S install macchanger
  elif [[ "$paman" == "IDK" ]]; then
    apt-get install macchanger
    apt install macchanger
    rpm install macchanger
    yum install macchanger
    dnf install macchanger
    pacman -S install macchanger
  else
    $pacman install macchanger
  fi
  if macchanger --help > /dev/null; then
    echo "[-] macchanger installed !"
  else
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)ERROR!"
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)MACCHANGER NOT INSTALLED!"
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)EXITING!"
    $stopAllFX; exit
  fi

  echo "[-] Copying files ..."
  cp mac-camo /usr/bin/
  echo "[-] Files copied !"

  echo "[-] Changing file permissions ..."
  chmod +x /usr/bin/mac-camo
  echo "[-] File permissions changed !"

  installComplete

}

# Linux install, Pt. 2
function linuxInstallPt2() {

  $green; $bold; $standoutStart; echo
  echo " OS: $os                "
  echo " macchanger installed: $macchangerInstalled "
  echo " Package Manager: $pacman "
  $standoutFinish; $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[*] ^--- $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Install with these settings?:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Yes"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)No"
  read -p ">>> " installWithTheseSettings
  if [[ "$installWithTheseSettings" == "0" ]]; then
    linuxInstallPt3
  elif [[ "$installWithTheseSettings" == "1" ]]; then
    installCancelled
  else
    macInstallPt2
  fi

}

# Linux install, Pt. 1
function linuxInstallPt1() {

  $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Which package manager do you use on this device?:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)apt-get"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)apt"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)2$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)rpm"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)3$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)yum"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)4$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)dnf"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)5$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)pacman"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)6$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)IDK"
  read -p ">>> " pacman
  if [[ "$pacman" == "0" ]]; then
    pacman="apt-get"
    linuxInstallPt2
  elif [[ "$pacman" == "1" ]]; then
    pacman="apt"
    linuxInstallPt2
  elif [[ "$pacman" == "2" ]]; then
    pacman="rpm"
    linuxInstallPt2
  elif [[ "$pacman" == "3" ]]; then
    pacman="yum"
    linuxInstallPt2
  elif [[ "$pacman" == "4" ]]; then
    pacman="yum"
    linuxInstallPt2
  elif [[ "$pacman" == "5" ]]; then
    pacman="pacman"
    linuxInstallPt2
  elif [[ "$pacman" == "6" ]]; then
    pacman="IDK"
    linuxInstallPt2
  else
    macInstallPt1
  fi

}

# Linux install, Pt. 0
function linuxInstallPt0() {

  $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Is $($bold)macchanger$($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white) installed on this device?:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Yes"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)No"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)2$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)IDK"
  read -p ">>> " macchangerInstalled
  if [[ "$macchangerInstalled" == "0" ]]; then
    macchangerInstalled="Yes"
    linuxInstallPt1
  elif [[ "$macchangerInstalled" == "1" ]]; then
    macchangerInstalled="No"
    linuxInstallPt1
  elif [[ "$macchangerInstalled" == "2" ]]; then
    macchangerInstalled="IDK"
    linuxInstallPt1
  else
    macInstallPt0
  fi

}

# MacOS install, Pt. 3
function macInstallPt3() {

  $white; $bold; echo

  echo "[-] Installing Homebrew ..."
  /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
  if brew ls --versions myformula > /dev/null; then
    echo "[-] Homebrew installed !"
    echo "[-] Updating Homebrew ..."
    brew update
    echo "[-] Homebrew updated !"
  else
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)ERROR!"
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)HOMEBREW NOT INSTALLED!"
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)EXITING!"
    $stopAllFX; exit
  fi

  echo "[-] Installing macchanger ..."
  brew install acrogenesis/macchanger/macchanger
  if macchanger --help > /dev/null; then
    echo "[-] macchanger installed !"
  else
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)ERROR!"
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)MACCHANGER NOT INSTALLED!"
    $red; $bold; echo "[!] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $red)EXITING!"
    $stopAllFX; exit
  fi

  echo "[-] Copying files ..."
  cp mac-camo /usr/bin/
  echo "[-] Files copied !"

  echo "[-] Changing file permissions ..."
  chmod +x /usr/bin/mac-camo
  echo "[-] File permissions changed !"

  installComplete

}

# MacOS install, Pt. 2
function macInstallPt2() {

  $green; $bold; $standoutStart; echo
  echo " OS: $os                "
  echo " Homebrew installed: $brewInstalled   "
  echo " macchanger installed: $macchangerInstalled "
  $standoutFinish; $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[*] ^--- $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Install with these settings?:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Yes"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)No"
  read -p ">>> " installWithTheseSettings
  if [[ "$installWithTheseSettings" == "0" ]]; then
    macInstallPt3
  elif [[ "$installWithTheseSettings" == "1" ]]; then
    installCancelled
  else
    macInstallPt2
  fi

}

# MacOS Install, Pt. 1
function macInstallPt1() {

  $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Is $($bold)macchanger$($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white) installed on this device?:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Yes"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)No"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)2$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)IDK"
  read -p ">>> " macchangerInstalled
  if [[ "$macchangerInstalled" == "0" ]]; then
    macchangerInstalled="Yes"
    macInstallPt2
  elif [[ "$macchangerInstalled" == "1" ]]; then
    macchangerInstalled="No"
    macInstallPt2
  elif [[ "$macchangerInstalled" == "2" ]]; then
    macchangerInstalled="IDK"
    macInstallPt2
  else
    macInstallPt1
  fi

}

# MacOS install, Pt. 0
function macInstallPt0() {

  $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Is $($bold)Homebrew$($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white) installed on this device?:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Yes"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)No"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)2$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)IDK"
  read -p ">>> " brewInstalled
  if [[ "$brewInstalled" == "0" ]]; then
    brewInstalled="Yes"
    macInstallPt1
  elif [[ "$brewInstalled" == "1" ]]; then
    brewInstalled="No"
    macInstallPt1
  elif [[ "$brewInstalled" == "2" ]]; then
    brewInstalled="IDK"
    macInstallPt1
  else
    macInstallPt0
  fi

}

# Installation and Configuration
function installAndConfig() {

  $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Please select your OS from the list below:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)MacOS"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Linux"
  read -p ">>> " os
  if [[ "$os" == "0" ]]; then
    os="MacOS"
    macInstallPt0
  elif [[ "$os" == "1" ]]; then
    os="Linux"
    linuxInstallPt0
  else
    installAndConfig
  fi

}

# Menu 0
function menu0() {

  $white; $bold; echo
  echo "[*] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Please select an option from the list below:"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)0$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Install and configure"
  $yellow; $bold; echo "        [$($white)1$($yellow)] $($stopAllFX; $bgBlack; $white)Spoof"
  read -p ">>> " spoofOrInstall
  if [[ "$spoofOrInstall" == "0" ]]; then
    installAndConfig
  elif [[ "$spoofOrInstall" == "1" ]]; then
    spoof
  else
    menu0
  fi

}; menu0

}; start
```

How can I make this work better?

Comment: Yay, a Bash coder that knows to use `tput`!  +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small thing - you can reduce the number of invocations of `tput` by storing the *output* of the `tput` commands rather than the command lines themselves, and then interpolating those output values when needed.

#### Example:

```
bgBlack=$(tput setab 0)
white=$(tput setaf 7)
stopAllFX=$(tput sgr0)
```

```
  read -p "[*] $stopAllFX$bgBlack${white}Select an interface: >>> " iface
```